# Getting data from a form using java

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<div></div>
    <div></div>
           <div></div>
            <div></div>
                <ul>
        <form id=the_main_form method="post">
                   <li>
                       <div></div>
                       <div> <h2> 
                <a onclick="xyz;" target="_blank" href="http://sample.com" style="text-decoration:underline;">This is sample</a>
                 </h2></div>
                       <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                      </li>
```

there are 50 li's like that

I have posted the snip of the html from a big HTML.

`<div> </div>`  => means there is data in between them removed the data as it is not neccessary.

I would like to know how the JSOUP- select statement be to extract the href and Text?

I selected  doc.select("div div div ul  xxxx");

where xxx is form ..shoud I give the form id (or) how should I do that

Comment: Is this the only <a> inside the form? or the first one?

Comment: Thank you for the response. edited question and there are multiple li's and yes there is only one a

Comment: one <a> inside each li? Do you want only the first one or all of them?

Comment: In each li there is div> <h2> 
                <a onclick="xyz;" target="_blank" href="http://sample.com" style="text-decoration:underline;">This is sample</a>
                 </h2></div>. and I want all the a;s

Comment: All the `<div></div>` lines are superfluous since they both open _and_ close a div.  The nesting you imply by indenting is incorrect.  If you really mean the divs are nested, then put the `</div>` tags in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Elements allLis = doc.select("#the_main_form > li ");
for (Element li : allLis) {
    Element a = li.select("div:eq(1) > h2 > a");
    String href = a.attr("href");
    String text = a.text();
}
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

```
Elements allLis = doc.select("#the_main_form > li ");
```

This part of the code gets all `<li>` tags that are inside the `<form>` with id `#the_main_form`.

```
Element a = li.select("div:eq(1) > h2 > a");
```

Then we iterate over all the `<li>` tags and get `<a>` tags, by first getting `<div>` tags ( the second one inside all `<li>`s by using index=1 -> `div:eq(1)`) then getting `<h2>` tags, where our `<a>` tags are present.

Hope you understand now! :)

Comment: HAshinmi,this works. can you try to make me understand this? #the_main_form is the form id and "> li " all the children to li??? and similarly you used eq(1) because it is the second div?

Comment: BTW its not `HAshinmi`, its `HashimR` :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.works;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

/*
 * @ author: sarath_sivan
 */

public class HtmlParserService {

    public static void parseHtml(String html) {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element linkElement = document.select("a").first();
        String linkHref = linkElement.attr("href"); // "http://sample.com"
        String linkText = linkElement.text(); // "This is sample"
        System.out.println(linkHref);
        System.out.println(linkText);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<a onclick=\"xyz;\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://sample.com\" style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">This is sample</a>";
        parseHtml(html);
    }

}
```

Hope you have the Jsoup Library in your classpath.

Thank you!